# Javascript tests using poltergeist and capybara accessing internal api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I am using capbara with poltergeist to run my javascript tests and i often get this error, it is trying to access internal api,it is even worse when my internet connection is off as more tests start failing, I am also using vcr and webmock to test external apis. What might the problem be

Failure/Error: visit user_session_url

```
    Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
   Request to 'http://www.example.com:65264/users/sign_in' failed to r 
   reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no 
   open resource requests
```

Comment: Does `www.example.com` resolve to the ip your app under test is being run on (usually 127.0.0.1) in your network environment?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a restriction on the app to allow traffic hitting internal API's.

On a side note, PhantomJS is not being actively supported/developed anymore. Consider alternative headless browser solutions. Chrome Headless was suggested by the guy that declared PhantomJS dead.